# How to write SQL below in order to display all details

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I don't know if I am doing the below method correctly when using sql but here it goes.

I want to display all exam details (exams details (Also know as Session), questions in exam, answers, penalty, images, videos etc) But the way I am trying to do it is one big query but it is not working as no rows are being displayed.

Below are what I want to display for one exam (and only one exam):

- Exam Details
- All questions in Exam
- All Answers to each question and marks each answer worth
- Penalty (see if enabled or not)
- Penalty marks for incorrect answers
- Images in question
- Videos in questions
- Audio in questions
- Module Details
- Student

Below show the fields each section above require from database:

- Exam Details

  `SessionId, SessionName, SessionDuration, TotalMarks, SessionWeight`
- All questions in Exam

  `QuestionId, QuestionNo, QuestionContent, NoofAnswers, QuestionMarks, OptionId, OptionType, ReplyId, ReplyType`
- All Answers to each question and marks each answer worth

`AnswerId, Answer, AnswerMarks`

- Penalty (see if enabled or not)

`PenaltyEnabled`

- Penalty answers

`PenaltyAnswerId, PenaltyAnswer, PenaltyMarks`

- Images in question

`ImageId, ImageFile`

- Videos in questions

`VideoId VideoFile`

- Audio in questions

`AudioId, AudioFile`

- Module Details

`ModuleId, ModuleNo, ModuleName`

- Student

`StudentId`

My question is how should the SQL code be written in order for all these data to be shown? Do I just need one big query or a lot of little queries? My attempt is at bottom of question but below is the database tables which shows details dealing with one exam and all its details.

**TABLES:**

**Student**

```
StudentId (PK)  StudentForename  StudentSurname
1              James            Parker
```

**Student_Session**

```
SessionId (FK)  StudentId (FK)
1              1
```

**Session**

```
SessionId (PK) SessionName  SessionDuration  TotalMarks  SessionWeight  ModuleId (FK)
1             AAA          01:00:00        30         20            1
```

**Module**

```
ModuleId (PK)  ModuleNo  ModuleName
1              CHI2513   ICT
```

**Question**

```
SessionId FK) QuestionId (PK)  QuestionNo QuestionContent NoofAnswers QuestionMarks OptionId (FK) ReplyId (FK)
1             4                1           Question 1      1           5              1            1
1             5                2           Question 2      1           3              2            1
1             6                3           Question 3      2           6              2            2
1             7                4           Question 4      3           7              5            2
1             8                5           Question 5      1           9              5            1
```

**Answer:**

```
AnswerId (PK) Answer  QuestionId (FK)
1              A       4
2              C       5
3              A       6
4              B       6
5              B       7
6              D       7
7              E       7
8              G       8
```

**Individual Answer**

```
IndividualId (PK)  AnswerId (FK) AnswerMarks  
1                    1              3       
2                    2              5       
3                    3              3       
4                    4              3       
5                    5              2       
6                    6              2       
7                    7              3       
8                    8              9
```

**Penalty**

```
PenaltyId(PK) SessionId (FK)  PenaltyEnalbed
1             1               1
```

**PenaltyMarks**

```
PenaltyAnswerId (PK) PenaltyAnswer PenaltyMarks QuestionId (FK)
1                     B            1            4
2                     C            1            4
3                     A            1            5
4                     B            1            5
5                     D            1            5
6                     C            2            6
7                     D            2            6
8                     A            1            7
9                     C            1            7
10                    F            1            7
11                    G            1            7
12                    A            0            8
13                    B            0            8
14                    C            1            8
15                    D            1            8
16                    E            1            8
17                    F            0            8
```

**Reply**

```
ReplyId (PK)  ReplyType
1               Single
2               Multiple
```

**Option_Table**

```
OptionId (PK)  OptionType
1               A-C        
2               A-D
3               A-E
4               A-F
5               A-G
```

**Image**

```
ImageId (PK)  ImageFile
1              ImageFile/Tulips.png
2              ImageFile/Daisys.png
```

**Video**

```
VideoId (PK) VideoFile
1              VideoFile/Speech.png
```

**Audio**

```
AudioId (PK) AudioFile
1               AudioFile/Song.png
```

**Image_Question**

```
   ImageQuestionId (PK) ImageId (FK) SessionId (FK)  QuestionNo (FK)
   1                    1             1                2
```

**Video_Question**

```
VideoQuestionId (PK) VideoId (FK) SessionId (FK)  QuestionNo (FK)
1                      1            1                   4
```

**Audio_Question**

```
AudioQuestionId (PK) AudioId (FK) SessionId (FK)  QuestionNo (FK)
1                      1            1                  5
```

Below was my failed attempt:

```
SELECT s.SessionId, 
       SessionName, 
       SessionDuration, 
       TotalMarks, 
       SessionWeight, 
       q.QuestionId, 
       q.QuestionNo, 
       QuestionContent, 
       QuestionMarks, 
       q.OptionId, 
       OptionType, 
       q.ReplyId, 
       ReplyType, 
       a.AnswerId, 
       Answer, 
       NoofAnswers, 
       AnswerMarks, 
       PenaltyEnabled, 
       PenaltyAnswerId, 
       PenaltyAnswer, 
       PenaltyMarks, 
       i.ImageId, 
       au.AudioId, 
       v.VideoId, 
       ImageFile, 
       AudioFile, 
       VideoFile, 
       s.ModuleId, 
       ModuleNo, 
       ModuleName, 
       ss.StudentId 
FROM   Student st 
       INNER JOIN Student_Session ss 
               ON st.StudentId = ss.StudentId 
       INNER JOIN Session s 
               ON ss.SessionId = s.SessionId 
       INNER JOIN Question q 
               ON s.SessionId = q.SessionId 
       INNER JOIN Answer a 
               ON q.QuestionId = a.AnswerId 
       INNER JOIN Individual_Answer ia 
               ON a.AnswerId = ia.AnswerId 
       LEFT JOIN Module m 
              ON s.ModuleId = m.ModuleId 
       LEFT JOIN Penalty p 
              ON q.SessionId = p.SessionId 
       LEFT JOIN Option_Table o 
              ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId 
       LEFT JOIN Reply r 
              ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId 
       LEFT JOIN Penalty_Marks pm 
              ON q.QuestionId = pm.QuestionId 
       LEFT JOIN Image_Question iq 
              ON q.QuestionId = iq.QuestionNo 
       INNER JOIN Image i 
               ON iq.ImageId = i.ImageId 
       LEFT JOIN Audio_Question aq 
              ON q.QuestionId = aq.QuestionNo 
       INNER JOIN Audio au 
               ON aq.AudioId = au.AudioId 
       LEFT JOIN Video_Question vq 
              ON q.QuestionId = vq.QuestionNo 
       INNER JOIN Video v 
               ON vq.VideoId = v.VideoId 
WHERE  s.SessionId = 1
ORDER  BY q.QuestionId
```

UPDATE:

Will the code below be able to insert QuestionId into Image_Question Table after questions submitted: (This is something I found on SO but updated to my table design)

```
ImageQuestionToken
{
  ImageToken (PK auto)
  SessionId
}

Image{
   ImageId 
   ImageFile
}

Image_Question
{
  Image_QuestionId
  ImageId FK references Image(ImageId)
  QuestionId FK references Question(QuestionId)

}

Question
{
  QuestionId (PK Auto)
  QuestionNo
  QuestionContent
  ....
}

TempImage
{
  ImageToken FK references ImageQuestionToken(ImageToken)
  ImageFile
}
```

And the logic like so:

1. User requests question form. Server sets token and includes in response to user.
2. User uploads picture including token. Image is stored in temporary table.
3. Step 2 repeated n times.
4. If user submits question with token value, an entry is placed in the questions table and an id is assigned. All images in the TempImage table that share the token get inserted to the image table with the now known QuestionId. The ImageQuestionToken entry is then deleted and cascade deletes the temp images in TempImage.
5. Else user doesn't submit question then files are deleted and ImageQuestionToken entry deleted.

Comment: need to post live source html for client side problems, not server code

Comment: my guess is that some one piece of data is missing and you really need OUTER joins not INNER joins.

Comment: YES me too thinks that there will be no videos for all questions nor image.

Comment: I wonder if total rewriting old unanswered questions in order to be able to start bounty without a 24 hour delay is fair use of this site. Also I wonder if getting rep for answering your own questions is fair too...

Comment: This is great that you provided so much detail, instead of the list of what you want can you post the data in the form of the desired result?

Comment: I had to use my scroll wheel like 10 times. You best to offer up some mo bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem with your foreign keys in these tables: Image_Question, Audio_Question, and Video_Question.

You are using the column QuestionNo which is not indexed by the table Question.
I would suggest replacing the columns as QuestionId instead and used their values.

```
Image_Question

ImageQuestionId (PK) ImageId (FK) SessionId (FK)  QuestionNo(FK)
   1                    1             1                2

Video_Question

VideoQuestionId (PK) VideoId (FK) SessionId (FK)  QuestionNo(FK)
   1                      1            1               4

Audio_Question

AudioQuestionId (PK) AudioId (FK) SessionId (FK)  QuestionNo(FK)
   1                      1            1               5
```

and your statement should look like this:

```
SELECT s.SessionId, 
       SessionName, 
       SessionDuration, 
       TotalMarks, 
       SessionWeight, 
       q.QuestionId, 
       q.QuestionNo, 
       QuestionContent, 
       QuestionMarks, 
       q.OptionId, 
       OptionType, 
       q.ReplyId, 
       ReplyType, 
       a.AnswerId, 
       Answer, 
       NoofAnswers, 
       AnswerMarks, 
       PenaltyEnabled, 
       PenaltyAnswerId, 
       PenaltyAnswer, 
       PenaltyMarks, 
       i.ImageId, 
       au.AudioId, 
       v.VideoId, 
       ImageFile, 
       AudioFile, 
       VideoFile, 
       s.ModuleId, 
       ModuleNo, 
       ModuleName, 
       ss.StudentId 
FROM   Student st 
       INNER JOIN Student_Session ss 
               ON st.StudentId = ss.StudentId 
       INNER JOIN Session s 
               ON ss.SessionId = s.SessionId 
       INNER JOIN Question q 
               ON s.SessionId = q.SessionId 
       INNER JOIN Answer a 
               ON q.QuestionId = a.AnswerId 
       INNER JOIN Individual_Answer ia 
               ON a.AnswerId = ia.AnswerId 
       LEFT JOIN Module m 
              ON s.ModuleId = m.ModuleId 
       LEFT JOIN Penalty p 
              ON q.SessionId = p.SessionId 
       LEFT JOIN Option_Table o 
              ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId 
       LEFT JOIN Reply r 
              ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId 
       LEFT JOIN Penalty_Marks pm 
              ON q.QuestionId = pm.QuestionId 
       LEFT JOIN Image_Question iq 
              ON q.QuestionNo= iq.QuestionNo
       LEFT JOIN Image i
               ON iq.ImageId = i.ImageId 
       LEFT JOIN Audio_Question aq 
              ON q.QuestionNo= aq.QuestionNo
       LEFT JOIN Audio au 
               ON aq.AudioId = au.AudioId 
       LEFT JOIN Video_Question vq 
              ON q.QuestionNo= vq.QuestionNo
       LEFT JOIN Video v 
               ON vq.VideoId = v.VideoId 
WHERE  s.SessionId = 1
ORDER  BY q.QuestionId
```

update:
You can use the column QuestionNo afterall, you could just add index so you don't have to overhaul your codes. hehehe

i suggest you add this:

```
ALTER TABLE `your_schema`.`Question` 
ADD INDEX `your_idx` (`QuestionNo` ASC);
```

and instead of these:

```
  LEFT JOIN Image_Question iq 
    ON q.QuestionId = iq.QuestionId -- from iq.QuestionNo
  LEFT JOIN Image i
    ON iq.ImageId = i.ImageId 
  LEFT JOIN Audio_Question aq 
    ON q.QuestionId = aq.QuestionId -- from aq.QuestionNo
  LEFT JOIN Audio au 
    ON aq.AudioId = au.AudioId 
  LEFT JOIN Video_Question vq 
    ON q.QuestionId = vq.QuestionId -- from vq.QuestionNo
  LEFT JOIN Video v 
    ON vq.VideoId = v.VideoId
```

you use these:

```
  LEFT JOIN Image_Question iq 
    ON q.QuestionNo= iq.QuestionNo
  LEFT JOIN Image i
    ON iq.ImageId = i.ImageId 
  LEFT JOIN Audio_Question aq 
    ON q.QuestionNo= aq.QuestionNo
  LEFT JOIN Audio au 
    ON aq.AudioId = au.AudioId 
  LEFT JOIN Video_Question vq 
    ON q.QuestionNo= vq.QuestionNo
  LEFT JOIN Video v 
    ON vq.VideoId = v.VideoId
```

Comment: Hi I can't change QuestionNo to QuestionId. Reason for this is that When user inserts images for example, it will upload images which users are creating questions where each question has a question number. Now we can't give each question a QuestionId until the questions have been fully completed and submitted, but as images are uploaded to questions before questions are completed and submitted, we don't know which questionid each image belongs to as those questions have not been submitted and inserted into database. When questions are inserted into db then that is when they get questionId

Comment: Does it make sense what I just said?

Comment: Wait a minute Joseph, in 10 mins can you look at an update in my question. I might have a way of somehow including `questionId` in `Image_Question` Table

Comment: I included an update, please look at update, erm I think only step 4 I do not understand because I do not know if I need to include another id in question table for reference. Can you show me the necessary inserts and select statements I need to do to achieve this token method in your answer. This will then mean questionid can be put in `Image_Question`, which matches what you said and you version of the big query can work and then I can give you points as it will all work (hopefully). Im asking you to do this because you will probably understand this a lot more

Comment: Hi, sorry I was busy with other stuffs. You can use the column `QuestionNo` afterall, you could just add index so you don't have to overhaul your codes.

Answer (score 2):

While I am not 100% sure of the exact result that you want.  Based on your existing query the issue is that you are using `INNER JOIN` on some of the tables when you should be using `LEFT JOIN`.

In your existing query you are using the following:

```
LEFT JOIN Image_Question iq 
  ON q.QuestionId = iq.QuestionNo 
INNER JOIN Image i 
  ON iq.ImageId = i.ImageId 
LEFT JOIN Audio_Question aq 
  ON q.QuestionId = aq.QuestionNo 
INNER JOIN Audio au 
  ON aq.AudioId = au.AudioId 
LEFT JOIN Video_Question vq 
  ON q.QuestionId = vq.QuestionNo 
INNER JOIN Video v 
  ON vq.VideoId = v.VideoId
```

The problem is that the `INNER JOIN` is checking for matching records on all fields but you might not have a record that exists in the `image`, `audio` or `video` tables so it is not returning anything.

Based on your details your query should be similar to this:

```
select st.studentid,
  s.sessionid,
  s.sessionname,
  s.sessionduration,
  s.totalmarks,
  s.sessionweight,
  q.questionid,
  q.questionno,
  q.questioncontent,
  q.noofanswers,
  q.questionmarks,
  q.optionid,
  ot.optiontype,
  q.replyid,
  r.replytype,
  a.answerid,
  a.answer,
  ia.answermarks,
  p.penaltyenabled,
  pm.penaltyanswerid, 
  pm.penaltyanswer,
  pm.penaltymarks,
  i.imageid,
  i.imagefile,
  v.videoid,
  v.videofile,
  ad.audioid,
  ad.audiofile,
  m.moduleid,
  m.moduleno,
  m.modulename
from Student st 
inner join Student_Session ss
  on st.studentid = ss.studentid
inner join session s
  on ss.sessionid = s.sessionid
inner join question q
  on s.sessionid = q.sessionid
inner join answer a
  on q.questionid = a.questionid
inner join Individual_Answer ia
  on a.answerid = ia.answerid
left join Option_Table ot
  on q.optionid = ot.optionid
left join reply r
  on q.replyid = r.replyid
left join module m
  on s.moduleid = m.moduleid
left join Penalty p
  on s.sessionid = p.sessionid
left join penalty_marks pm
  on q.questionid = pm.questionid
left join image_question iq  -- note I am joining on both session and question
  on s.sessionid = iq.sessionid
  and q.questionid = iq.questionno
left join image i  -- this should be a left join not inner join
  on iq.imageid = i.imageid
left join video_question vq -- note I am joining on both session and question
  on s.sessionid = vq.sessionid
  and q.questionid = vq.questionno
left join video v  -- this should be a left join not inner join
  on vq.videoid = v.videoid
left join audio_question aq  -- note I am joining on both session and question
  on s.sessionid = aq.sessionid
  and q.questionid = aq.questionno
left join audio ad  -- this should be a left join not inner join
  on aq.audioid = ad.audioid
where  s.SessionId = 1
order by q.QuestionId
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/610b1/17).

This is returning all of the data that you have requested above. Sample:

```
| STUDENTID | SESSIONID | SESSIONNAME | SESSIONDURATION | TOTALMARKS | SESSIONWEIGHT | QUESTIONID | QUESTIONNO | QUESTIONCONTENT | NOOFANSWERS | QUESTIONMARKS | OPTIONID | OPTIONTYPE | REPLYID | REPLYTYPE | ANSWERID | ANSWER | ANSWERMARKS | PENALTYENABLED | PENALTYANSWERID | PENALTYANSWER | PENALTYMARKS | IMAGEID | IMAGEFILE | VIDEOID |            VIDEOFILE | AUDIOID |          AUDIOFILE | MODULEID | MODULENO | MODULENAME |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|         1 |         1 |         AAA |        01:00:00 |         30 |            20 |          4 |          1 |      Question 1 |           1 |             5 |        1 |        A-C |       1 |    Single |        1 |      A |           3 |              1 |               1 |             B |            1 |  (null) |    (null) |       1 | VideoFile/Speech.png |  (null) |             (null) |        1 |  CHI2513 |        ICT |
|         1 |         1 |         AAA |        01:00:00 |         30 |            20 |          4 |          1 |      Question 1 |           1 |             5 |        1 |        A-C |       1 |    Single |        1 |      A |           3 |              1 |               2 |             C |            1 |  (null) |    (null) |       1 | VideoFile/Speech.png |  (null) |             (null) |        1 |  CHI2513 |        ICT |
|         1 |         1 |         AAA |        01:00:00 |         30 |            20 |          5 |          2 |      Question 2 |           1 |             3 |        2 |        A-D |       1 |    Single |        2 |      C |           5 |              1 |               3 |             A |            1 |  (null) |    (null) |  (null) |               (null) |       1 | AudioFile/Song.png |        1 |  CHI2513 |        ICT |
|         1 |         1 |         AAA |        01:00:00 |         30 |            20 |          5 |          2 |      Question 2 |           1 |             3 |        2 |        A-D |       1 |    Single |        2 |      C |           5 |              1 |               5 |             D |            1 |  (null) |    (null) |  (null) |               (null) |       1 | AudioFile/Song.png |        1 |  CHI2513 |        ICT |
|         1 |         1 |         AAA |        01:00:00 |         30 |            20 |          5 |          2 |      Question 2 |           1 |             3 |        2 |        A-D |       1 |    Single |        2 |      C |           5 |              1 |               4 |             B |            1 |  (null) |    (null) |  (null) |               (null) |       1 | AudioFile/Song.png |        1 |  CHI2513 |        ICT |
```

Comment: @ITppl this has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The key problem: often, no rows will be returned using an inner join off of an outer joined table

I have subqueried, using microsoft SQL syntax. Hope it helps. See my warnings at the bottom, and ignore the create procedure statement if you like and instead just declare and set the @SessionID to 1 at the top.

```
create procedure GetStuff(
    @SessionID as integer
    ) as

declare @StudentID int -- you may need to use a different data type
select @StudentID = StudentID from Student_Session where SessionID = @SessionID

-- now we can at least remove the sessions table from the join list.

SELECT s.SessionId, 
       SessionName, 
       SessionDuration, 
       TotalMarks, 
       SessionWeight, 
       q.QuestionId, 
       q.QuestionNo, 
       QuestionContent, 
       QuestionMarks, 
       q.OptionId, 
       OptionType, 
       q.ReplyId, 
       ReplyType, 
       a.AnswerId, 
       Answer, 
       NoofAnswers, 
       AnswerMarks, 
       PenaltyEnabled, 
       PenaltyAnswerId, 
       PenaltyAnswer, 
       PenaltyMarks, 
       i.ImageId, 
       au.AudioId, 
       v.VideoId, 
       ImageFile, 
       AudioFile, 
       VideoFile, 
       s.ModuleId, 
       ModuleNo, 
       ModuleName, 
       ss.StudentId 
FROM   Student st 
       INNER JOIN Student_Session ss 
               ON st.StudentId = ss.StudentId 
       INNER JOIN Session s 
               ON ss.SessionId = s.SessionId 
       INNER JOIN Question q 
               ON s.SessionId = q.SessionId 
       INNER JOIN Answer a 
               ON q.QuestionId = a.AnswerId 
       INNER JOIN Individual_Answer ia 
               ON a.AnswerId = ia.AnswerId 
       LEFT outer JOIN Module m 
              ON s.ModuleId = m.ModuleId 
       LEFT outer JOIN Penalty p 
              ON q.SessionId = p.SessionId 
       LEFT outer JOIN Option_Table o 
              ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId 
       LEFT outer JOIN Reply r
              ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId 
       LEFT outer JOIN Penalty_Marks pm 
              ON q.QuestionId = pm.QuestionId 
        -- you can't inner join off of an outer joined table, or you'll get no rows for the entire query. I've nested the query, which is bad practice but... practical for getting this monster of a query working.
       LEFT outer JOIN (select c3.ImageID, c3.ImageFile from Image_Question as a1 inner join Images as b1 on a1.QuestionNo = b1.QuestionNo inner join Image as c1 on a1.ImageID = c1.ImageID)
               ON q.QuestionID = iq.QuestionID
        -- you can't inner join off of an outer joined table, or you'll get no rows for the entire query. I've nested the query, which is bad practice but... practical for getting this monster of a query working.
       LEFT outer JOIN (select b2.AudioID, b2.AudioFile from Audio_Question as a2 inner join Audio as b2 on a2.AudioID = b2.AudioID) as aq
              ON q.QuestionId = aq.QuestionNo 
        -- you can't inner join off of an outer joined table, or you'll get no rows for the entire query. I've nested the query, which is bad practice but... practical for getting this monster of a query working.
        left outer join (select b3.VideoID, b3.VideoFile from Video_Question as a3 inner join Video as b3 on a3.QuestionID = b3.QuestionID) as vq 
WHERE  
    st.StudentID = @StudentID
    and 
    s.SessionId = @SessionID
ORDER  BY q.QuestionId 
go
```

Warnings:
You will really want to break this down to seperate peices for displaying in your client application. For instance, you need a master/detail display for Exams and ExamDetails, otherwise you would have to suppress repeating values in the output shown to the user.
For instance, your output would look like this, conceptually:

```
<Exam Detail Fields>    <Exam Detail Fields>
first one unique        What is the color of your DOG?
repeat          What is the color of your CAT?
repeat          What is the color of your CAR?
repeat          What is the color of your HAT?
```

Note the repetitive values on the left that you would have to suppress.

Comment: Hi, when doing this task, am I better off making the big query as I am doing now or am I better creating smaller queries (each query performing the task o retrieving data for certain actions (exam details, questions, answers etc)? You see my plan to create the big query then use php loops to retrieve the details correctly.

Comment: Im getting this error: Every derived table must have its own alias. Can you show an sql fiddle example so I can see what data should look like.

Answer (score 0):

Well , Try it in small shifts : what I mean is:- Execute the query part by part
remove some joins at first (remove most of them ),and add them one by one ,I do the same for my huge queries to track where is the actual problem, or which conditions are making the main differences for getting the resulted rows. just an Idea. Cheers!

And i think

```
 LEFT JOIN Image_Question iq 
              ON q.QuestionId = iq.QuestionNo
```

will give you null values

As q.QuestionId starts form 4 and iq.QuestionNo  is 2

```
INNER JOIN Image i 
               ON iq.ImageId = i.ImageId
```

And all the values in  Iq fields resulted from Left outer joins  are null.So any Inner Join on them is Sure to give you null results.

Comment: Hi, when doing this task, am I better off making the big query as I am doing now or am I better creating smaller queries (each query performing the task o retrieving data for certain actions (exam details, questions, answers etc)? You see my plan to create the big query then use php loops to retrieve the details correctly.

Comment: Sorry ! you got it wrong ! I am not telling to create small queries ! test them part by part ! . 
:Cheers again. And I thing the problem I have figured out above .Please check it .

Comment: You have serious Data Problems As I see in the Above Query .

Comment: q.QuestionId = iq.QuestionNo(LOJ)    will never match to give any value . Check your table values. with that  iq.ImageId = i.ImageId (Inner join will never match).

Comment: Can I ask you a question as you probably have more experience than me in databases, when retrieving exam, question, answer details etc would YOU do it this way. Looking at the tables and seeing all the data, would you write it as I am attempting doing it as a big query or would you do it differently? Do you think in the other answer norman has a right method of doing it or would you do that differently as well as he mentioned his method may be bad practice

Comment: Some ERP development companies even don't use FK and PK at all . Yours idea is also fine , Check the INNER OUTER joins and PK and FK.  With no disrepect user1723760 , what do you expect if you have worng data in tables , would you expect them to come fine data at you hand in a situation where you have a query which says " if it does not match ,please don't give me any results"that is what inner joins stands for. Big queries are still does not seems a problem to me . But I test them with all the possibilities of data , writing them is not just the work done sometimes .